# Does Control.Controls property return recursively nested controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

The MSDN documentation for System.Windows.Forms.Control.Controls property (for example, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx)) states:

> Use the Controls property to iterate through all controls of a form, *including nested controls*.

I'm at a loss as for what does "nested controls" properly mean here.
To illustrate an issue, I made a form, consisting of:

- a button
- a ListBox
- a groupbox with a button inside.

The code

```
MessageBox.Show(Controls.Count.ToString());
```

yields the answer 3. Based on my understanding of the docs, I have assumed it would provide 4 instead (counting the button inside the groupbox).
The same behavior is observed if the groupbox is replaced by the panel.

What does the aforementioned phrase about nested controls actually mean?

Comment: Good question. Also nice to see rare person who actually read documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Control.Controls` is a collection of that control's *immediate* children. Therefore your form's Controls collection will have 3 controls. And your GroupBox's Controls collection will have 1 control (the button).

I'm not really sure what that comment in the documentation was getting at, aside from perhaps (although not so eloquently) hinting that you can use this property recursively to get at all nested controls. For example:

```
static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllDescendantControls(this Control c)
{
    return c.Controls.Cast<Control>()
        .Concat(c.Controls.SelectMany(x => x.GetAllDescendantControls()));
}
```

Comment: A small notice: I could only get your example to work using `c.Controls.Cast<Control>` instead of simple `c.Controls`, the ControlCollection itself isn't castable to IEnumerable<Control>

Comment: @alexdelphi ahh yes you might have to do that. Some of those WinForms collections are only IEnumerable. Thanks for the comment